# Log-Likelihood ratio derivation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, information-theory

I am struggling to understand the derivation of the log likelihood in the proof of Lemma 1 in Kauffman14 (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.4443.pdf).

I will give a bit of context: the lemma is about a lower bound on the sample complexity for multi-armed bandit through a change of measure argument. The log-likelihood in the derivation after $t$ rounds where the agent chooses arm $A_t$ and observe reward $Z_t$ is stated as
$$L_{t}=L_{t}\left(A_{1}, \ldots, A_{t}, Z_{1}, \ldots, Z_{t}\right):=\sum_{a=1}^{K} \sum_{s=1}^{t} \mathbb{1}_{\left(A_{s}=a\right)} \log \left(\frac{f_{a}\left(Z_{s}\right)}{f_{a}^{\prime}\left(Z_{s}\right)}\right)$$

My question is concerns how to write this from what I know to be the log likelihood ration

$$L_{t}=L_{t}\left(A_{1}, \ldots, A_{t}, Z_{1}, \ldots, Z_{t}\right):= \log \left(\frac{f_{a}\left(A_1,Z_1,\dots,A_t,Z_t\right)}{f_{a}^{\prime}\left(A_1,Z_1,\dots,A_t,Z_t\right)}\right)$$

Do they apply some sort of conditioning or some martingale properties on the expectation of the sigma algebra generated by the observations? It would be very helpful to see the complete derivation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/475455/119261.

Comment: I removed it from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They may have used three steps

- $f_{a}\left(A_1,Z_1,\dots,A_t,Z_t\right) = \prod\limits_{s=1}^t   f_{a}\left(A_s,Z_s\right)$ assuming independence, and similarly for $f'$
- $\log\left( \frac{\prod\limits_{s=1}^t f_{a}\left(A_s,Z_s\right)}{\prod\limits_{s=1}^t f'_{a}\left(A_s,Z_s\right)}\right)=\sum\limits_{s=1}^t \log\left( \frac{f_{a}\left(A_s,Z_s\right)}{f'_{a}\left(A_s,Z_s\right)}\right) $ using properties of logarithms
- $\log\left(\frac{f_{a}\left(A_s,Z_s\right)}{f'_{a}\left(A_s,Z_s\right)}\right) = \sum\limits_{a=1}^K \mathbf 1_{(A_s=a)} \log\left(\frac{f_{a}\left(Z_s\right)}{f'_{a}\left(Z_s\right)}\right)$ since each $A_s$ only takes one value

Comment: The fact is that each action should depend on past observation since $A_t$ is $ \mathcal{F}_{t-1}$-measurable, where  $\mathcal{F}_{t} = \sigma(A_1,Z_1,\dots A_{t},Z_{t})$ is the sigma-algebra generated by te sequence of observations $A_1,Z_1,\dots A_{t},Z_{t}$. So the first point here would not hold, correct?